# rails acts_as_follower postgres throwing error

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Just tried adding acts_as_follower gem to a rails 4 app - and am getting this error

Environment:

- rails 4
- postgresql
- acts_as_follower (0.2.1)
- devise

User model acts as follower and following

```
PG::NotNullViolation at /follows
ERROR:  null value in column "followable_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, null, null, 21, User, f, 2014-03-03 06:35:49.655726, 2014-03-03 06:35:49.655726).
```

My code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_follower
  acts_as_followable
end

follower = User.first
following= User.last
follower.follow(following)
```

Comment: I suspect it doesn't like being added to an existing data model that already has data in it from before the gem was installed. But that's just a guess, I've never used it (or Rails).

Answer (score 0):

In development mode you can run

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Update your seed data and then run

```
rake db:seed
```